# How to send response from an interceptor, and halt further execution?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have an interceptor, and under a certain condition I want to send a string response to the browser and then halt execution completely.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Override the preHandle method and return false if you want to stop execution.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.getWriter().write("something");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How send this response as Json? something like `{ "code":"ERR404", "message":"Not Found"}`

Comment: add `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: Any idea how to send the response in spring error message like format : 
 {
 "timestamp": "",
 "status": ,
 "error": "",
 "message": "",
 "path": ""
}

Comment: this works in 2022

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this which will return a json response to the client

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.getWriter().write("{ \"error_description\": \"Invalid Value\"}");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setStatus(400);
    return false;
}
```